# ProgressBar display only end

Tags: swift, swift2, progress-bar

ProgressBar only shows the progress when the loop ends.
How do in this example for the bar to be updated in real time?

```
@IBAction func btnStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    for var xx:Float = 0 ; xx<=1.0; xx=xx+0.00001 {
        progressView.setProgress(xx, animated: false)
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
```

Answer (score 1):

UI only updates in the main loop and at the end of the current scope,

so try this

```
@IBAction func btnStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector("process", toTarget: self, withObject: nil)
}

func process() {
    for var xx:Float = 0 ; xx<=1.0; xx=xx+0.00001 {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            progressView.setProgress(xx, animated: false)
        })
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
```